# Ion checkbox binding two values

Tags: ionic-framework, checkbox

I have been struggling with ion-checkboxes and I really need some help. I am developing a questionnaire that has true or false answers. I want the true and false to appear as ion-checkboxes. Something like this

```
 <ion-row>
 <ion-col size="1">
  <ion-checkbox [checked]="option1" (ionChange)=change1()>
  </ion-checkbox>
 </ion-col>
 <ion-col>True </ion-col>
 <ion-col size="1">
  <ion-checkbox [checked]="option2" (ionChange)=change1()>
  </ion-checkbox>
 </ion-col>
 <ion-col>False </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

I want the ionChange to ensure that only one checkbox is checked as true at a time. In other worlds, if the user selects true, then the false checkbox (option2) will automatically become false. If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to do it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a51emq

Home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  avengers = {
    stark: true,
    steve: false
  }
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
filterData(){

    this.avengers.steve = !this.avengers.steve
    this.avengers.stark = !this.avengers.stark

}
}
```

Home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card padding>
  <ion-checkbox [checked]="avengers.stark" ([ngModel])='avengers.stark' (click)="filterData()"></ion-checkbox>  Stark
  </ion-card>  
  <ion-card padding>
  <ion-checkbox [checked]="avengers.steve" ([ngModel])='avengers.steve' (click)="filterData()">Stark</ion-checkbox>  Steve
  </ion-card>  

</ion-content>
```